# RSpec - How do nested before :all and before :each blocks interact?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I encountered an issue with some Web UI Automation using RSpec and Selenium/Capybara/SitePrism. It's related to the combination of `before :all` and `before :each` clauses that occur in the code, and perhaps especially in my `spec_helper` file.

Up until now, I've been running rspec against one spec file at a time. Each spec file required a `spec_helper` file, which included the following:

```
spec_helper.rb:
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.before(:all) do
      # 1) Code to configure WebDriver and launch Browser is here
    end
  end
```

The spec files themselves contain their own `before` blocks for various reasons. Most of them contain something like the following:

```
test_a_spec.rb:
  describe "Page A" do
    before :all do
      # 2) Log in to web site, maybe load the test page in question
    end
    it "does this thing" do
      # 3) Test this thing
    end
    it "does that thing" do
      # 4) Test that thing
    end
  end
```

This worked fine as long as I was running RSpec against individual spec files. When I tried tagging some of my examples and then running against the whole spec folder, I had a problem. The `before :all` block in `spec_helper.rb` didn't prepend itself to every file, as I thought it would, but instead ran once at the beginning. All the spec files after the first were expecting a clean browser to be launched by `spec_helper` and to do the log in part themselves, but the browser wasn't clean and was already logged in, so that wasn't good.

Changing the `before :all` in `spec_helper.rb` to a `before :each` seemed like the natural solution, so I did, and suddently my tests instantly failed with an error claiming that `rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given`. This happened to some of my tests but not all, and through process of elimination I realized it was only tests that had their own `before :all` blocks that were failing. It appears that the `before :all` in the spec file is superceding the `before :each` in the `spec_helper` file. So it was trying to log in before it had launched a browser.

This vexes me. I am terribly vexed. I had sort of assumed two things:

- I assumed `before :each` was on equal footing with `before :all`, and in fact imagine it like a `before :all` plus more, in a sense. The idea that a `before :all` would supercede a `before :each` seems weird to me.
- I assume all these `before` blocks were subject to nesting in a reasonable way. That is, a `before :all` block should fire once before all the things below it, which would mean firing within each iteration of a `before :each` block that might contain the `before :all` block. Also, if a `before :each` contains some code and then a describe statement below it has a `before :all`, the `before :each` code should still fire before the `before :all` code. Maybe it does do that, I'm just not sure at this point.

Questions:

1) What kind of behavior is my `spec_helper` file actually producing? If I were to take that same behavior and put it into one of the spec files itself, for instance, what would that look like? Would the `before :each` with the browser launch code wrap around all the code in the spec file in some sort of implicit `describe` block? Does the `before :each` get inserted into the outermost describe block, and therefore have to compete with the spec file's `before :all` block?

2) I could "solve" this by abandoning all `before :all` blocks in my tests, but I like the flexibility of the way things are, and since this is UI Automation and speed is a factor, I don't really want to be opening a new browser and logging in for each describe, even though I'm aware that this would be ideal for keeping every test separated from the others. Do I have to/want to do just that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To address the part of your question not already covered by https://stackoverflow.com/a/22489263/1008891, the `require` method will not reload any file already loaded previously, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22489263/1008891. This contrasts with the `load` method, which acts like a "copy/paste" of the file contents wherever it is used.

I'm not saying that if you changed all your `requires` to `loads` that you'd get the same result as running the individual files, as there may be other global state that affects the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: I feel like messing with `require` vs `load` probably isn't the right choice, and I'm also unsure if it would alter the behavior at all. I had expected there to be some difference in how `spec_helper` would act on different spec files, but apparently there is none. The configuration in `spec_helper` will apparently apply to the examples and example groups that `rspec` deems part of the run, regardless of which files they live in. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I agree changing to `load` is probably not the right choice and may not change anything anyway.

Comment: Was the other answer not sufficient to address your other questions?  In short, you can use `before(:suite)` in your configuration for "once per RSpec invocation" operations and "before(:all)` in your configuration for "once per top-level example" example operations. Those don't "compete" with `before` calls at the example level; they are complementary to them.

Comment: The conclusion that I'm coming to is that it's likely a better plan to just use `before :each` exclusively and avoid `before :all` like it's the devil.

I believe the main source of my confusion when I wrote the question had to do with the way `spec_helper`'s `before` block would be distributed among a group of files. Thinking about files at all seemed to be the wrong direction. What I wanted was a `before :all` in `spec_helper` to magically become a `before :all` at the top of every top-level example group in each file.

In the end, I think I must agree to abandon `before :all`.

Answer (score 0):

The RSpec documentation (http://rspec.info/documentation/3.3/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Hooks.html#before-instance_method) provides some very useful information about how before blocks interact and the order in which they are run, but they do recommend avoiding before(:context) [aka before(:all)].

FYI, note that the after blocks are run in the reverse order fin which before blocks are.